# How to use bash scripting to calculate an average?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, math

I'm currently working for a little game card project with c++ but I need some stats, here I would like to make an average of the number of round before a victory. I try bash to do it but I have a little error and I'm pretty new to bash.

here is the code :

```
#!/bin/bash
i="1"
moyenne="1"

while [ $i -le 40 ]
do
    moyenne = $(($moyenne + ./a.out 2>&1 | tail -1))
    ((i++))
done
```

and there is my error

> ./script.sh: line 7: 1 + ./a.out 2>&1 | tail -1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "./a.out 2>&1 | tail -1")

Comment: You want to use `$(./a.out 2>&1 | tail -1)`.

Comment: ok i change my line with this `avg = $(($avg + $(./a.out 2>&1 | tail -1)))` but I'm getting this error now ...  `./script.sh: line 7: avg: command not found`

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ would be a good place to start. (You can't have spaces around the `=` in an assignment, which that -- or any other good static checking tools -- would point out).

Comment: ...by the way, do you want floating-point results here? Native bash is probably not the best idea, then; see [BashFAQ #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022).

Comment: Nice for the spaces between `=` thanks a lot @CharlesDuffy I'm gonna look for the floating problem thanks a lot !

Comment: @PabloClsn I wrote a really long answer to your question including a solution with floating point arithmetic. But since the question was closed I can't send it. To not waste my effort if you want it I can email it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems: The spaces around the equal sign -- Bash is sensitive about this -- and the way you add (+) the two operands without evaluating with `$()`.

I don't know exactly what your `a.out` returns, but substituting it with a simple `echo 1`, this adds up to 41:

```
moyenne=$(($moyenne + $(echo 1 2>&1 | tail -1)))
```